# Convert PDF to .ipynb (recover Jupyter notebook from PDF)

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

I have a PDF file that was created from a Jupyter notebook, but the original .ipynb file is lost.
Is there some tool that would help to convert PDF to .ipynb?

Answer (score 1):

that may not be possible since .ipynb file contains pieces of code that requires for it to execute in jupyter notebook ..so the best option is to try to copy the contents from the pdf on to new .ipynb file and execute it.

Comment: My concern is not for the code, it will be easy to copy-paste code and execute it again. But the problem is in text markdown and LaTeX, the is a lot of formatted text and many complex formulas, so it will take a lot of time to restore it by hand. Since PDF uses LaTeX, I believe it should be possible to convert PDF to .ipynb, I just can't find such a tool on my own.

Answer (score 0):

PDF to Python is straightforward, but it takes several steps.  Essentially you must extract the code to text format and then parse and clean it up to get it back into an executable format.

1. Save the PDF as text file.  Adobe Acrobat does this well, but there are several Python PDF libraries to extract text from any PDF.
2. parse the text to identify and capture the Python code (as text strings)
3. Convert the Python text strings to Python tokens.
4. Clean or lint the Python code to format it so that it will run without errors due to indentation.  You can use the Python "black" module or PEP8 linter to clean up indentation.

There are numerous examples of parsing Python in HTML format to Jupyter Notebook format. Spyder and VSCode linters work well to fix indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This [website](https://www.vertopal.com/) claims it can do that, however the output - at the moment- is just a big chunk of HTML which can be displayed as a markdown cell in a Notebook, so I had to split that output int small pieces then used that output as a task to ChatGPT with the following prompt:

```
Convert the following HTML code to Jupyter Notebook.
Separate each block of code into a new Cell.
Put the text block in Markdown cell, and the python code in Code block.
Remove unnecessary HTML code, and remove unnecessary format from the text.
Response without without comment.
Format your response in JSON Jupyter Notebook file format: {input_code}
```

Make sure the result is valid `JSON` in jupyter notebook format, so it can be saved into `*.ipynb` file then opened in Jupyter Notebook.
This process can automate using `openai` API if the request body is small enough.

Answer (score -2):

Not possible to convert pdf into ipynd. But you can use google lens it will help you in copy pasting.

Comment: This is strictly not true.  Your answer should be removed.